# Get the quantity of the currently selected variant - cart.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to get the exact inventory quantity of a currently selected variant

I have tried this code, but it returns all the quantities of the variables. I only need the one that is selected in the cart

```
{% endraw %}

{% assign product_qty = 0 %}

{% for variant in product.variants %}

{% if variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}
<p>{{variant.inventory_quantity}}</p>
{% assign product_qty = product_qty | plus: variant.inventory_quantity %}

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Output: 
-3 
0 
0
0

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Add if in:

```
{% if variant.selected %}
<p>{{variant.inventory_quantity}}</p>
{% endif%}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it